# How to create speed animation bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I will be glad to get some help with how to do a speed animation bar for android app. Something like [what is shown here](http://ffb01754f828acf9087d-a290154ed149b36fff218ed99ffa5fbb.r95.cf3.rackcdn.com/phone%20speed%20animation.html) so it fills up automatically but for an app.

So far I [found this code](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/), which pretty resembles what I was aiming for but 
I don't want the animation to show on a pop up, but as part of the page.

If you are not sure please point me to the right source so I will figure out how this works.

Any help would be much appreciated:)

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939715/android-progress-bar-with-padding)

Comment: you are doing nothing wrong, just add progress bar in `main` layout file and reference it. Find my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add progress base in your activity layout `(R.layout.main)`;

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/mybar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp" />
```

And instead of doing this

```
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
```

do this after setContentView();

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mybar);
```