# Android SeekBar - Progress line doesn't follow the thumb

Tags: android, padding, progress, seekbar

I have a seekbar in my layout and I've set the paddings and thumbOffset to 8dp on the xml file.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/graph"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:thumbOffset="8dp"
    android:progress="97"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_seekbar" />
```

The problem I'm having is, when the progress is near the end (but not the end), the progress line will be ahead (if progress > 50) or behind (if progress < 50). This image shows what's happening (The progress is set to 97 and 3 respectively):

[image].

You can see the progress line ahead the thumb in the first one and before it on the second one.

It doesn't happen if I set the paddings and thumbOffset to the default values, but then, the thumb won't start inside the rectagle, it will be avove it's edge.

[image]
.

The solution I'm looking for is a way to make the background bigger, so the thumb will be inside, but the progress line will follow the center of the thumb.

Here's how I defined the background of the seek bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- view background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="#000000" >
    </solid>

    <!-- view border color and width -->
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" >
    </stroke>

    <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

The main problem is the progress line will always start at the edge of the rectangle, while the thumb may not because of the paddings and thumbOffset. If I find a way to make the line start and end at the same position as the thumb do, it would work too.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12219589/3531756) and try to wrap progressbar in a layout like it's done here and give padding to that layout.

Comment: I can't do it (I think) because it's a seekbar, not a progressbar. But if it's possible, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Use that process, just replace his ProgressBar with your SeekBar. Basically you're to add your SeekBar in a layout like he did and give padding to that layout. In that way you won't be giving padding to your SeekBar, hence solving your issue.

Comment: If I do like you said, the border will be bigger than the whole widget, not bigger than the thumb's smaller circle.

Comment: Yes, that might happen in that case. Is it important to give left padding?

Comment: Yes, I want the thumb to always be inside of the rectangle. But the progress line must start and end at the same position as the center of the thumb, not on the rectangle's edges.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72634/discussion-between-tushar-and-gabriel-salla).

Comment: @GabrielSalla have you got the solution

Comment: No, I moved on :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution just set - `android:thumbOffset="0dp"`

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in style.xml

```
<style name="SeekBarMyTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

Create a layout **mytheme_scrubber_control_disabled_holo** in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_disabled_holo" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_focused_holo" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_normal_holo" />
</selector>
```

Create a layout **mytheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light** in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
                android:drawable="@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_track_holo_light" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
                    android:drawable="@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_secondary_holo" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
                    android:drawable="@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_primary_holo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Create a layout **mytheme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_light** in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_disabled_holo" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_focused_holo" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_normal_holo" />
</selector>
```

After all this, write this line in your style of appTheme

```
<item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/SeekBarMyTheme</item>
```

And this will be your seekbar layout:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" />
```

**NOTE**:- *mytheme_scrubber_control_normal_holo, mytheme_scrubber_control_pressed_holo, mytheme_scrubber_control_focused_holo, mytheme_scrubber_control_normal_holo* these all in  the drawable folder and are .png files.

Hope it will help you,
Let me know in case of any concern.

Comment: NOTE:-
@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_normal_holo,
@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_pressed_holo,
@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_focused_holo,
@drawable/mytheme_scrubber_control_normal_holo

these all are the drawables.(png files)....

Comment: My drawables are all xml files, I'm not using images. And I have drawables for the background and the progress fill. Are all these steps necessary? I'm kind of new to android and it looks a bit confusing

Comment: @gabrielSalla: its ok, if u having xml files drawable,,
just follow these steps,
instead of drawables u can put your own xml files..

Comment: @gabrielSalla: chk now, i have upate this layout too "mytheme_scrubber_control_disabled_holo"