# Android-Horizontal Gradient Progress bar showing full progress

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, progress-bar

Progress bar with progress drawable is not showing correct progress. It's showing full progress instead of set progress value.

progress bar xml

```
 <ProgressBar
       style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rewardScore"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/userProgress"
       android:max="100"
       android:background="@drawable/progress_white_bg"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_height="10dp"
       android:progress="40"
       android:progressDrawable="@drawable/gradient_progress"
    />
```

gradient_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>

        <corners android:radius="100dp"/>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:endColor=  "@color/white"
            />
        </shape>
     </item>

     <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
       <shape>
         <corners android:radius="100dp"/>

        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/progress_gradient_one"
            android:endColor="@color/progress_gradient_two"
            />
       </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue is in gradient_progress drawable.  set this property in gradient 
 tag of second item:  android:useLevel="true":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>

        <corners android:radius="1dp" />
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#fff"
            android:startColor="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="1dp" />
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#6aae33"
            android:startColor="#e61313"
            android:useLevel="true" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: can you please look into the issue? I'm stuck with this

Comment: is issue still with progress?

Comment: You can take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12219589/4693331

Comment: it's taking the full progress no matter what i set if i use progress drawable

Comment: you need to set " android:useLevel="true"" property. pls check answer i have updated.

Answer (score 3):

the trick is in adding the `<clip>` tag to the progress item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>

        <corners android:radius="100dp"/>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:endColor=  "@color/white"
            />
        </shape>
     </item>

     <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
       <clip>
         <shape>
           <corners android:radius="100dp"/>

           <gradient
               android:startColor="@color/progress_gradient_one"
               android:endColor="@color/progress_gradient_two"
            />
         </shape>
       </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```