# (Android) Progress Bar Customization: put vertical line on a bar, put arrow picture above a bar

Tags: android, android-widget, progress-bar

I need some help about progress bar customization.

I want any idea about how to do like these 2 pictures:

[Click here to view pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unpPt.png)

1.On left-side picture, there is a red vertical line on the progress bar.

2.On Right-Side picture, there is an arrow picture with vertical line on the progress bar. Also, there are many colors on one progress bar.

What are classes ,methods or whatever idea should be implement for drawing these?

Thanks in advance :)

*P.S. Picture Source,
Left: My Diet Diary Calorie Counter,
Right: Calorie Counter,Viaden Gaming Limited*

Comment: Have you tried looking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581812/custom-progress-bar-in-android maybe those give you ideas.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I figure out is to extend ProgressBar with a custom class of your own and override the ondraw method to draw what you want in your progress bar.

Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669655/possible-to-do-rounded-corners-in-custom-progressbar-progressdrawable) and [here](http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/04/android-custom-progressbar-with-rounded-corners/).