# Right side edge cornering issue in Android's Progressbar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I used this code to create a corner on edges in the Progressbar but it does not work same for the right side

```
 <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
  <clip>
   <shape>
    <corners android:radius="35dip" />
    <gradient android:startColor="#990000" android:endColor="#E6E8FA" />

   </shape>
  </clip>
 </item>
```

[image: here] is what it looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the clip is clipping based on the ProgressBar's whole container size, so it is rounded over the invisible corners at the left.  When it reaches 100%, it should look correct.  I do not think you can accomplish the look you want with just a clip drawable.

Comment: Looking around, it seems this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078809/progress-bar-rounded-on-both-sides-in-android) would be a good place to start.