# Android Material Design rounded progress_bar

Tags: android, material-design, android-progressbar

I´m working on an app wich uses different progress bars, and I want them to look as the ones in Google fit, with rounded cornes.
[image: Google fir bars]
I have a custom drawable for each bar with different colors, and it rounds the outside corners but not the inside corners, as you can see here:
[image: My bars]
My custom drawable is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/progress_bar_rounded" />
            <solid android:color="@color/progressbarBackground" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/progress_bar_rounded" />
                <solid android:color="@color/progressbarGreen" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

An the progress bars code is:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar_high"
    android:id="@+id/GreenProgressBar"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_green_progressbar" />
```

I could use some libraries as https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar , but as it is such a simple thing i think it´s not worth it.
I also have been looking on different threads, but nothing has worked for me.
Any idea, without having to work with .9.png images, if possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you could check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21923928/3711562  and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5354554/3711562

Comment: Yes, I had already seen that thread, but i prefer not to ude .9.png because the color may change, and I don´t understand the second post.

Comment: @Javierd98 you could use `progressTint` to change the color

Comment: seems the 9 patches are not really required, just replace them with shapes

Answer (score 11):

Use the `scale` tag rather than `clip`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/progress_bar_rounded" />
            <solid android:color="@color/progressbarBackground" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%" android:useIntrinsicSizeAsMinimum="true">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/progress_bar_rounded" />
                <solid android:color="@color/progressbarGreen" />
                <size android:width="@dimen/progress_bar_rounded"/>
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks!! This fixed the main issue, now the problem is that when the progress is small, the progressbar doesn´t fit the background and looks ugly. How could i fix it??
http://i.imgur.com/vnak3Av.png

Comment: one possible solution is to give the shape a width and use `useIntrinsicSizeAsMinimum` so that it does not scale below that

Comment: I have tried adding `android:useIntrinsicSizeAsMinimum="true"` on scale, but the problem is still there