# Progress bar with round corners and multiple colors

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I've read already similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078809/progress-bar-rounded-on-both-sides-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646574/progress-bar-with-rounded-corners) and are good solutions if you only want to show a single progress bar with rounded corners, but in my case I want to show a progress made out of multiple "sub-progress" colors like in the image below:

[image: progress bar]

What I've done so far is to code a LinearGradient implementation like this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999839/horizontal-lineargradient-with-android) but it looks squared in the corners.

How can I obtain this progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found this class [PaintDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/PaintDrawable.html) which I can set as background of any View, and surprisingly I can set a Shape to this Drawable, so if I use the [RoudRectShape](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.html) it seems rounded as I want it to be, my final code is as follows:

```
        // mRatios is a View
        ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
            @Override
            public Shader resize(int i, int i1) {
                LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, mRatios.getWidth(), 0,
                        barColorsArray,
                        barRatiosArray,
                        Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

                return lg;
            }
        };
        PaintDrawable paintDrawable = new PaintDrawable();

        // not sure how to calculate the values here, but it works with these constants in my case
        paintDrawable.setShape(new RoundRectShape(new float[]{100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100}, null, null));
        paintDrawable.setShaderFactory(sf);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            mRatios.setBackgroundDrawable(paintDrawable);
        } else {
            mRatios.setBackground(paintDrawable);
        }
```